# Express sessions not persisting only for deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, express-session, nodejs-express-server

I am having this problem where my project works locally but when deployed, the sessionID is different after redirecting and the front end and back end fails to communicate with each other, I've tried custom domains, and deploying on different services, I have used render.com and vercel now.

This is my backend index.js
I've tried different ways to fix the problem, using redis, using cookie parser and changing static files.

When I click login, it correctly goes to spotify and logs me in there, then when I am redirected back, I think session is not persisting and only loading screen is there.

```
const express = require('express');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// app.use(session({
//   secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
//   resave: false,
//   saveUninitialized: true,
//   cookie: {
//     secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
//     sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'None' : 'Lax'
//     //domain: '.onrender.com'
//   }
// }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.FRONT_URL, // adjust if your frontend port is different
  credentials: true
}));

//Redis setup
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const redisClient = createClient({
  url: 'rediss://red-cmcp61f109ks73921rng:WbyyCCp36c1oIHIO5irK8nwAN0nlyU5P@ohio-redis.render.com:6379',
  legacyMode: true// Your Redis URL
});
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
// Session setup with Redis


app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false, // You can set this to false to comply with laws that require permission before setting a cookie
  name: 'HaromonyCookie',
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'None' : 'Lax',
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    domain: process.env.DOMAIN // Should be true if using HTTPS
  }
  // Add other configurations as needed
}));

redisClient.on('connect', () => console.log('Redis client connected'));
redisClient.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

// Serve static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build')));

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri: process.env.SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI
});

// have to rewrite this to because I am not storing token in spotifyApi object
app.post('/refresh', (req, res) => {
  const refreshToken = req.session.user.refreshToken;
  spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
  spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken().then(data => {
    res.json({
      accessToken: data.body['access_token'],
      expiresIn: data.body['expires_in']
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error refreshing access token' });
  });
} );

app.get('/api/token', (req, res) => {
  console.log("token endpoint hit")
  console.log('Session ID:', req.sessionID);
  console.log('Cookies sent:', req.cookies);
  if (req.session.user && req.session.user.accessToken) {
    console.log("sending token")
    res.json({ accessToken: req.session.user.accessToken });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized: No active session' });
  }
});

// Redirect users to this endpoint for Spotify login, then redirect them to the /callback endpoint
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log("STEP 1")
  console.log("--------------------")
  console.log("login enpoint hit")
  console.log("--------------------")
  const scopes = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email', 'playlist-read-private', 'playlist-modify-private', 'playlist-modify-public'];
  res.redirect(spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes));
  
}); 

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('Could not log out, please try again');
    } else {
      res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
      res.status(200).send('Logged out');
    }
  });
});

// Spotify will redirect users to this endpoint after login
app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  console.log("STEP 2")
  console.log("--------------------")
  console.log("callback endpoint hit")
  console.log("--------------------")
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0');
  res.set('Pragma', 'no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
  res.set('Expires', '0'); 
  const error = req.query.error;
  const code = req.query.code;

  if (error) {
    console.error('Callback Error:', error);
    res.send(`Callback Error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }

  spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(data => {
    const accessToken = data.body['access_token'];
    const refreshToken = data.body['refresh_token'];
    const expiresIn = data.body['expires_in'];
    const expiryTime = new Date().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000;
    console.log('Session ID:', req.sessionID);
    console.log('Cookies received:', req.cookies);

    req.session.user = {
      accessToken: accessToken,
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
      expiresIn: expiresIn,
      expiryTime: expiryTime
    };

    req.session.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving session:', err);
        res.send(`Error saving session: ${err}`);
      } else {        
        console.log("saved")
        console.log(req.session)
        // In your Express route after successful authentication
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Redirecting to front URL');
          res.redirect(`${process.env.FRONT_URL}/auth/callback`);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error getting Tokens:', error);
    res.send(`Error getting Tokens: ${error}`);
  });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/authContext';

const AuthCallback = () => {
    const { fetchTokens } = useContext(AuthContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAndSetTokens = async () => {
            console.log("AuthCallback reached and fetching tokens...")
            const tokens = await fetchTokens();
            if (tokens) {
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', tokens);
                localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);
                // Redirect to home or other page after successful login
                window.location.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_FRONT}/home` || "localhost:3000/home";
            }
        };
        fetchAndSetTokens();
    }, [fetchTokens]);

    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Or some loading indicator
};

export default AuthCallback;
```

In the backend it shows that I have succesfully signed in, saved the session and redirected to the front. It shows in the log that the session IDs are different.

I have tried not using redis, only using the default session, it didn't work, I have tried everything like trust proxy settings etc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the redis session config middleware

```
//Configure session middleware
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    secret: 'yoursecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, // if true only transmit cookie over https
        httpOnly: false, // if true prevent client side JS from reading the cookie 
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 // session max age in miliseconds
    }
}))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).